# From Ingress to IngressRoute with CertManager, HTTP01 Challenge and Let's Encrypt ClusterIssuer

Tags: traefik, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, ingress-route

I have a Kubernetes (v1.25.2) cluster running with `cert-manager` 1.11.0 and `Traefik` 2.9.6.
For some services I want `Let's Encrypt` to auto sign certificates. For some reason, it feels nicer, to use `IngressRoute` instead of `Ingress`.  I just can't get the IngressRoute to create the certificate.
Now, I have the a `ClusterIssuer`:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: my@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: traefik
```

and, working, corresponding `Ingress`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-name-websecure
  annotations:
   cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
    - host: my.host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: linkingservice
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
       - my.host.com
      secretName: some-secret-name-tls
```

---

This works, nice. Instead, with `IngressRoute` the base resource is this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: myapp-other-name-websecure
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`other.host.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: linkingservice
          port: 80
  tls:
    # certResolver: ??? # resolve what? Doesn't link with the ClusterIssuer
    # issuerRef: ??? # doesn't exist (anymore)
```

Now, I've tried to:

- just as for the `Ingress` to use the `annotations`: `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod`. Which is being ignored
- use the `tls.certResolver`, which doesn't work, because it doesn't exist. Should I create one? I expect The `ClusterIssuer` to create the certificate and secret, just as it does for `Ingress`.
- I also saw the `issuerRef` as option in the `tls` section, but that doesn't appear to exist.

I thought I read that the `IngressRoute` is like a layer on top of the k8s default `Ingress`, so it should be something logical/similar

---

FYI: the `ClusterIssuer` and `Ingress` will also work for `Nginx`, when you replace the `solvers.http01.ingress.class` with `nginx`, likewise for the `Ingress`'s `spec.ingressClassName`. (perhaps also without, but I can't test)

Answer (score 4):

Now, I did find a way, but still feels like more work than should be necessary. The thing here is to create the `Certificate` and link that to the `ClusterIssuer`, that certificate then creates a `Secret`. This secret needs to be added to the `spec.tls.secretName`, like:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my.host.com-cert
spec:
  secretName: my.host.com-secret
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  dnsNames:
    - my.host.com
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
spec:
...
  tls:
    secretName: my.host.com-secret
```

---

I've also tried for, `certResolver`. But the `CertificateResolver` from `cert-manager` was discontinued in `v0.15.0`; alternatively the `CertificateRequest`, but this was also discontinued in `cert-manager` version `0.9.0`. The suggested way seems to be the previous described one.

---

I revisited the `Traefik` deployment [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml#L757) where I found there is a field with `certResolvers`, from their file:

```
certResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    # for challenge options cf. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/
    email: email@example.com
    dnsChallenge:
      # also add the provider's required configuration under env
      # or expand then from secrets/configmaps with envfrom
      # cf. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/#providers
      provider: digitalocean
      # add futher options for the dns challenge as needed
      # cf. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/#dnschallenge
      delayBeforeCheck: 30
      resolvers:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
    tlsChallenge: true
    httpChallenge:
      entryPoint: "web"
    # It has to match the path with a persistent volume
    storage: /data/acme.json
```

Which makes me wonder. If you set this up, then probably the:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
spec:
  tls:
    certResolver: letsencrypt
```

can work

Answer (score 0):

The reason your tls section in the IngressRoute doesn't work like the Ingress is that cert-manager has a component called [Ingress-shim](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/), which monitors Ingress resources in the cluster and creates certificates for any missing secrets listed in the Ingress.

It simply isn't built to monitor IngressRoute yet. Now that Traefik, Nginx and other Ingress Controllers are moving to CRD's, I assume that cert-manager will have to add a way to monitor Ingress-like CRD's too, not just native Ingresses.

Like you said, you'll need to create a separate Certificate resource to request the certificate, then specify the secret name in the IngressRoute. The certResolver things you mentioned are for Traefik's built-in Let's Encrypt issuer. But you can't use this to replace Cert-Manager unless you're using Traefik Enterprise.

I'm personally trying to figure out how (if) I can link multiple Certificate secrets to a single IngressRoute, like I was able to to in an Ingress. In other words, an IngressRoute with multiple hostnames and a Certificate for each hostname, that is managed by Cert-Manager.